# mutt: keybind to run external script just before imap-fetch-mail

Tags: email, imap, mutt, offlineimap

I use `offlineimap` to manage receiving mail from my IMAP server. I use folders in `mutt` which `offlineimap` populates to view them. I would love to be able to bind a key to run the `offlineimap` external script, followed by mutt's `imap-fetch-mail` command.

Is there any way to do this?

I can do it separately, for example:

```
macro index "A" "|offlineimap\n"
bind index "B" imap-fetch-mail
```

Just can't figure out if there's a way to do both on the same key.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Both can be combined into a single macro.

1. `offlineimap` executable needs to be wrapped within  and
2. followed by neomutt function `imap-fetch-mail`

```
macro index,pager A "<shell-escape>offlineimap<enter><imap-fetch-mail>" "Sync mail"
```